# Beginner to Python: How to loop Mathematics Game properly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner to Python and I am having trouble looping this code. I was wondering if anyone could help me loop this code properly, so that when the User wants to quit the game (exit code 'xxx') and they press  to play the game again, the round heading resets so that it outputs round 1 out of 10 instead of 3 out of 10.

Sorry, it is a bit wrong but if anyone could help me I would be very grateful.

This is the outcome:

```
How many questions do you want to answer: 10
What game mode do you want to play (1. Addition 2. Subtraction 3. Multiplication 4. Division)? 1
########################
### Question 1 of 10 ###
########################
What is 9 + 8?  17
  
Question 1 | Result: Correct | Your Answer: 17.0 | Correct Answer: 17
   
Press <Enter> if you wish to continue the game, if you wish to quit type 'xxx': 
    
########################
### Question 2 of 10 ###
########################
What is 2 + 8?  10
    
Question 2 | Result: Correct | Your Answer: 10.0 | Correct Answer: 10
    
Press <Enter> if you wish to continue the game, if you wish to quit type 'xxx': xxx
    
If you wish to play the game again press <ENTER>, if you do not want to play the game again type 'xxx': 
How many questions do you want to answer: 10
What game mode do you want to play (1. Addition 2. Subtraction 3. Multiplication 4. Division)? 1
########################
### Question 3 of 10 ###
########################
What is 18 + 9?
```

This is the code:

```
#Round looping component version 1
#The Round Looping does not work as intended
#The Game History and Statistics does not work as intended (not currently in the code)

import random

def check_how_many_questions():
    while True:
        #Ask the User how many questions they want to answer if they want to play the
        #option where they can choose how many questions they want
        #to answer of if they want to play the continuous question option
        response = input("How many questions do you want to answer: ")

        how_many_questions_error = "Please input either an integer that is more than 0 or <ENTER>."
#If ifinite mode is not chosen, check response is an integer more than 0
        if response != "":
            try:
                response = int(response)

#If response is too low, go back to the start of the loop and display an error message to help user
                if response < 1:
                    print(how_many_questions_error)
                    continue

            except ValueError:
                print(how_many_questions_error)
                continue

        return response

#Game Mode Input Checker Function
def game_mode_input_checker(question):
    while True:

        #Error message
        error_message = "Error please input an Integer between 1 and 4 (1. Addition 2. Subtraction 3. Multiplication 4. Division)"

        try:
            #It is an float input in the case the User inpurs a valid input but just with a .0
            response = float(input(question))

            #If User's response is 1 return the response
            if response == 1:
                return response

            #If User's response is 2 return the response
            elif response == 2:
                return response

            #If User's response is 3 return the response
            elif response == 3:
                return response

            #If User's response is 3 return the response
            elif response == 4:
                return response

            #If User's response is not 1,2,3,4 print the <ERROR> message
            else:
                print(error_message)
                print()
                continue

        #If the User inputs an invalid value print the <ERROR> message
        except ValueError:
            print(error_message)
            print()

#Input Checker
def input_checker(question):
    while True:
        try:
            #It is an float input in the case the User inputs a calid input but just with a .0
            response = float(input(question))
            return response
        # Error message will be printed out to the User
        except ValueError:
            print("<ERROR> Please enter an Integer\n")
            continue

#Continue the game function
def continue_game(question):
    valid = False
    while not valid:
        response = input(question).lower()

        if response == "":
            return response

        elif response == "xxx":
            return response

        #If response is not "" or 'xxx' Error message will display to the User
        else:
            print()
            print("<Error> please enter either <Enter> or 'xxx'")
            print()

#Statement generator
#Decorates the statements in the Lucky Unicorn game
def statement_generator(statement, decoration):

    sides = decoration * 3

    statement = "{} {} {}".format(sides, statement, sides)
    top_bottom = decoration * len(statement)

    print(top_bottom)
    print(statement)
    print(top_bottom)

    return ""

#Main routine goes here

#Game Summary
game_summary = []

#Questions answered correct
questions_answered_correct = 0

#Questions answered incorrect
questions_answered_incorrect = 0

#Number of question answered
number_of_questions_answered = 0

game_loop = ""
while game_loop == "":

    user_choice_of_questions = check_how_many_questions()

    #Asks the User what game mode they want to play (1. Addition 2. Subtraction 3. Multiplication 4. Division)
    game_mode = game_mode_input_checker("What game mode do you want to play (1. Addition 2. Subtraction 3. Multiplication 4. Division)? ")

    while number_of_questions_answered < user_choice_of_questions:

        #If the User's Choice is <ENTER> the User has decided to answer the Continuous Question's option
        if user_choice_of_questions == "":
            heading = "Continuous Question: Question {}".format(number_of_questions_answered + 1)

        #If the User's Choice is not <ENTER> the User has decided to play the User Question number choose option
        else:
            heading = "Question {} of {}".format(number_of_questions_answered + 1, user_choice_of_questions)

            #Game Mode 1. Addition
        if game_mode == 1:

            #Displays to the User the Question Number
            statement_generator(heading, "#")

            #Number 1 that is in the first position before
            #The addition is a random integer between 0 and 20
            number_1 = random.randint(0,20)
            #Number 2 that is in the first position before
            #The addition is a random integer between 0 and 20
            number_2 = random.randint(0,20)
            #The answer is equal to Number 1 + Number 2
            answer = number_1 + number_2

            #The question asked to the User
            #The Input Checker is a float input in the case the User input the correct answer but just with a .0
            response = input_checker("What is {} + {}?  ".format(number_1, number_2))

            #If the User's response is equal to the answer (Number 1 + Number 2) the User gets the question 'Correct'
            if response == answer:
                result = "Correct"
                question_outcome = "Question {} | Result: {} | Your Answer: {} | Correct Answer: {}".format(number_of_questions_answered + 1, result, response, answer)
                print()
                number_of_questions_answered += 1
                questions_answered_correct += 1


            #If the User's response is not equal to the answer (Number 1 + Number 2) the User gets the question 'Incorrect'
            else:
                result = "Incorrect"
                question_outcome = "Question {} | Result: {} | Your Answer: {} | Correct Answer: {}".format(number_of_questions_answered + 1, result, response, answer)
                print()
                number_of_questions_answered += 1
                questions_answered_incorrect += 1


            print(question_outcome)

            #End game if the number of rounds has been played
            if number_of_questions_answered == user_choice_of_questions:
                break

            #If the number of rounds played is more than or equal to
            #One the User will be asked if they wish to continue the game or if they wish to
            #Quit the game they should input 'xxx'
            if number_of_questions_answered >= 1:
                print()
                game_loop = continue_game("Press <Enter> if you wish to continue the game, if you wish to quit type 'xxx': ")
                print()

            #If the User inputs 'xxx' when they are asked if they want to continue the game or not
            #The Game Loop will end
            if game_loop == "xxx":
                break

        #Game Mode 2. Subtraction
        elif game_mode == 2:

            #Displays to the User the Question Number
            statement_generator(heading, "#")

            #Number 1 that is in the first position before
            #The subtraction is a random integer between 0 and 50
            number_1 = random.randint(0,50)
            #Number 2 that is in the first position before
            #The subtraction is a random integer between 0 and 20
            number_2 = random.randint(0,50)
            #The answer is Number 1 - Number 2
            answer = number_1 - number_2

            #If number 2 is bigger than number 1
            #The answer is equal to Number 2 - Number 1
            #This is set so the User does not have to answer negate subtraction questions
            if number_2 > number_1:
                answer = number_2 - number_1

            #The question asked to the User if the answer is equal to Number 1 - Number 2
            if answer == number_1 - number_2:
                response = input_checker("What is {} - {}? ".format(number_1, number_2))

            #The question asked to the User if tbe answer is equal to Number 2 - Number 1
            else:
                response = input_checker("What is {} - {}? ".format(number_2, number_1))

            #If the User's response is equal to the answer (Number 1 - Number 2/Number 2 - Number 1)
            #The User gets the question 'Correct'
            if response == answer:
                result = "Correct"
                question_outcome = "Question {} | Result: {} | Your Answer: {} | Correct Answer: {}".format(number_of_questions_answered + 1, result, response, answer)
                print()
                number_of_questions_answered += 1
                questions_answered_correct += 1

                #If the User's response is not equal to the answer (Number 1 - Number 2/Number 2 - Number 1)
                #The User gets the question 'Incorrect'
            else:
                result = "Incorrect"
                question_outcome = "Question {} | Result: {} | Your Answer: {} | Correct Answer: {}".format(number_of_questions_answered + 1, result, response, answer)
                print()
                number_of_questions_answered += 1
                questions_answered_incorrect += 1

            print(question_outcome)

            #End game if the number of rounds has been played
            if number_of_questions_answered == user_choice_of_questions:
                break

            #If the number of rounds played is more than or equal to
            #One the User will be asked if they wish to continue the game or if they wish to
            #Quit the game they should input 'xxx'
            if number_of_questions_answered >= 1:
                print()
                game_loop = continue_game("Press <Enter> if you wish to continue the game, if you wish to quit type 'xxx': ")
                print()

            #If the User inputs 'xxx' when they are asked if they want to continue the game or not
            #The Game Loop will end
            if game_loop == "xxx":
                break

        #Game Mode 3. Multiplication
        elif game_mode == 3:

            #Displays to the User the Question Number
            statement_generator(heading, "#")

            #Number 1 that is in the first position before
            #The multiplication is a random integer between 0 and 12
            number_1 = random.randint(0,12)
            #Number 2 that is in the first position before
            #The multiplication is a random integer between 0 and 12
            number_2 = random.randint(0,12)
            #The answer is Number 1 x Number 2
            answer = number_1 * number_2

            #The question asked to the User
            response = input_checker("What is {} x {}? ".format(number_1, number_2))

            #If the User's response is equal to the answer (Number 1 x Number 2)
            #The User gets the question 'Correct'
            if response == answer:
                result = "Correct"
                question_outcome = "Question {} | Result: {} | Your Answer: {} | Correct Answer: {}".format(number_of_questions_answered + 1, result, response, answer)
                print()
                number_of_questions_answered += 1
                questions_answered_correct += 1

            #If the User's response is not equal to the answer (Number 1 x Number 2)
            #The User gets the question 'Incorrect'
            else:
                result = "Incorrect"
                question_outcome = "Question {} | Result: {} | Your Answer: {} | Correct Answer: {}".format(number_of_questions_answered + 1, result, response, answer)
                print()
                number_of_questions_answered += 1
                questions_answered_incorrect += 1

            print(question_outcome)

            #End game if the number of rounds has been played
            if number_of_questions_answered == user_choice_of_questions:
                break

            #If the number of rounds played is more than or equal to
            #One the User will be asked if they wish to continue the game or if they wish to
            #Quit the game they should input 'xxx'
            if number_of_questions_answered >= 1:
                print()
                game_loop = continue_game("Press <Enter> if you wish to continue the game, if you wish to quit type 'xxx': ")
                print()

            #If the User inputs 'xxx' when they are asked if they want to continue the game or not
            #The Game Loop will end
            if game_loop == "xxx":
                break


        #Game Mode 4. Division
        elif game_mode == 4:

            #Displays to the User the Question Number
            statement_generator(heading, "#")

            #Number 1 that is in the first position before
            #The division is a random integer between 0 and 12
            number_1 = random.randint(0,12)
            #Number 2 that is in the first position before
            #The division is a random integer between 0 and 12
            number_2 = random.randint(0,12)
            #The Product answer is Number 1 x Number 2
            product_answer = number_1 * number_2
            #The answer is equal to Number 2 beacuse that is what
            #The Product answer / Number 1 is equal to
            answer = number_2

            #The question asked to the User is what is the Product answer / Number 1
            response = input_checker("What is {} / {}? ".format(product_answer, number_1))

            #If the User's response is equal to the answer (Product answer / Number 1 = Number 2)
            #The User gets the question 'Correct'
            if response == answer:
                result = "Correct"
                question_outcome = "Question {} | Result: {} | Your Answer: {} | Correct Answer: {}".format(number_of_questions_answered + 1, result, response, answer)
                print()
                number_of_questions_answered += 1
                questions_answered_correct += 1

            #If the User's response is not equal to the answer (Product answer / Number 1 = Number 2)
            #The User gets the question 'Incorrect'
            else:
                result = "Incorrect"
                question_outcome = "Question {} | Result: {} | Your Answer: {} | Correct Answer: {}".format(number_of_questions_answered + 1, result, response, answer)
                print()
                number_of_questions_answered += 1
                questions_answered_incorrect += 1

            print(question_outcome)

            #End game if the number of rounds has been played
            if number_of_questions_answered == user_choice_of_questions:
                break

            #If the number of rounds played is more than or equal to
            #One the User will be asked if they wish to continue the game or if they wish to
            #Quit the game they should input 'xxx'
            if number_of_questions_answered >= 1:
                print()
                game_loop = continue_game("Press <Enter> if you wish to continue the game, if you wish to quit type 'xxx': ")
                print()

            #If the User inputs 'xxx' when they are asked if they want to continue the game or not
            #The Game Loop will end
            if game_loop == "xxx":
                break

    game_loop = continue_game("If you wish to play the game again press <ENTER>, if you do not want to play the game again type 'xxx': ")

print("Thank You for playing the Quiz Quest Game")
```

Comment: Please, divide your text into sentences. It's not clear what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the `number_of_questions_answered`  variable when the user types `xxx`:

```py
# If the User inputs 'xxx' when they are asked if they want to continue the game or not
# The Game Loop will end
if game_loop == "xxx":
    number_of_questions_answered = 0
    break
```